# CSS - Re-position Element

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to move the "pagination" area to be above the slider images.

Is this easy enough to achieve?

Currently they are below the slider images: http://slidesjs.com/examples/standard/

How do I do this?

Here is the CSS code used:

```
/*
    Slideshow
*/

#slides {
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    left:4px;
    z-index:100;
}

/*
    Slides container
    Important:
    Set the width of your slides container
    Set to display none, prevents content flash
*/

.slides_container {
    width:570px;
    height:270px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    display:none;
}

/*
    Each slide
    Important:
    Set the width of your slides
    If height not specified height will be set by the slide content
    Set to display block
*/

.slides_container a {
    width:570px;
    height:270px;
    display:block;
}

/*
    Next/prev buttons
*/

#slides .next,#slides .prev {
    position:absolute;
    top:107px;
    left:-39px;
    width:24px;
    height:43px;
    display:block;
    z-index:101;
}

#slides .next {
    left:585px;
}

/*
    Pagination
*/

.pagination {
    margin:26px auto 0;
    width:100px;
}

.pagination li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 1px;
    list-style:none;
}

.pagination li a {
    display:block;
    width:12px;
    height:0;
    padding-top:12px;
    background-image:url(../img/pagination.png);
    background-position:0 0;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.pagination li.current a {
    background-position:0 -12px;
}
```

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css class it will work for you

```
.pagination
{
   position:relative;
   top:-332px;
}
```